# MySQL - if condition optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

Just wondering, how this query will be handled by MySQL, will sum() calculated twice if sum(credits) != NULL or does MySQL has optimization in place for such queries.

```
select if(sum(credits)=NULL, 0, sum(credits)) from ......
```

Thanks

Comment: `sum` happens only once and not twice

Answer (score 0):

If won't work.  The first condition is always false.  The correct way to compare to `NULL` is `IS NULL`, not `=`.

Just use this construct:

```
select coalesce(sum(credits), 0)
```

Comment: thanks, I stand corrected on the syntax but what happens if IS NULL used, will it be calculated twice?

Comment: @Yusuf . . . That depends on the database, but probably yes for MySQL.  However, the calculation of the `sum()` is trivial in comparison to the work for the aggregation in general (and this is not repeated).  So the extra work should be trivial (it could be more important with a "harder" function such as `count(distinct)`).

Answer (score 0):

**Using IF**

```
SELECT IF(sum(credits) IS  NULL, 0 ,sum(credits)) .....
```

IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)

If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns expr2; otherwise it returns expr3. IF() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used

**Using IFNULL**

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(credits), 0) .....
```

**Using COALESCE**

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(credits), 0) .....
```

Refer : [MySQL Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is something we shouldn't worry about. With SQL we tell the DBMS what to do, not how to do it.

It is very, very likely that the DBMS will compute `sum(credits)` only once. It would seem rather stupid if not. However, this is not dictated by the SQL standard, so the DBMS programmers are free to choose how to code this. They *could* write the DBMS such that `sum(credits)` is computed twice. We cannot know whether they did or not, but as mentioned it is not likely and we shouldn't worry about it either.